# Json file request produce "(413) Request Entity Too Large"。

Tags: c#, .net, json, webserver, powerbi

I have a json file more than 10,000 rows

so when I request to Power BI

I'll get a error message

```
(413) Request Entity Too Large。
```

if the Json file < 10,000 rows this code is can work

so how I can fix this problem about the rows too mush

this is my code

```
string ColumnValuesJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"PowerBI_Column_Values.json");

//POST web request
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ColumnValuesJson);

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Console.WriteLine(byteArray.Length);
Console.ReadLine();
//
using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    /*Time*/
    ProcessTime.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("20,000 Rows  {0} ms", ProcessTime.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: See [413 “Request Entity Too Large” error with uploading a file](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2330) for approaches for configuring the HTTP server upstream.